# Is CryptoStream FlushFinalBlock GUARANTEED to Throw an Exception When the Key is Wrong?

Tags: .net, encryption, cryptography, aes

I know `CryptoStream`'s `FlushFinalBlock` method throws when the padding is wrong which likely means the key was wrong.

What I'm trying to figure out is whether this is a bullet-proof method of testing the authenticity of the key itself, i.e, whether `FlushFinalBlock` is *guaranteed* to throw if given the wrong key. Or, put differently, is it possible for the wrong key to yield a result that throws no exception but is just garbled output? If it is possible what is the rough likelihood of this? (I'm asking about AES256 specifically).

Assume I don't know what the encrypted data is and have no control over its encryption, so I have no way to validate it other than through a decryption attempt.

Comment: No, it's not bulletproof because a wrong key could also generate a valid padding by chance, which would then not throw an exception. Valid paddings for PKCS#7 are 0x01, 0x0202,..., which would occur with a probability of 1/256, 1/256^2,... for a wrong key, which is not negligible (at least for the cases with few padding bytes).

Comment: Ah, I see. Then I suppose if the data length is a whole multiple of 16 (for AES) there is no padding and thus no wrong key would throw? And furthermore it sounds then that there is no truly bulletproof way to know that the key is right unless you know some content within the underlying message? Thank you that's what I needed to know. Feel free to resubmit this as an answer.

Comment: For AES using an authenticated encryption mode like GCM will give you a check on key correctness also.

Comment: Regarding the question whether an exception is always thrown with a wrong key, see this online example https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yk2jBB: In the 2nd test, decryption is done with a key that was *not* used for encryption. The decryption is (of course) not successful (gibberish), but *no* exception is thrown, because the end of the decrypted data is 0x0202, which is compliant with the padding scheme (here PKCS#7). So the answer is: No, a wrong key does not necessarily throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you @Topaco for a direct answer. Again if you make this an answer I'll accept. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterMoore - You're welcome. I' ve summarized my comments in an answer and focus mainly on the .NET example, which easily illustrates when and with which probability a wrong key doesn't cause an exception. I omit the topic authenticated encryption and details of PKCS#7Padding, as these are already addressed in the comment and other answer.

Comment: For the sake of completeness it's worth mentioning my original motive for asking this, which is I had a (very momentary) thought that I could test a password - which doubles as an AES encryption key when hashed - solely by trying to decrypt the data being accessed. But I quickly realized if the .NET methods are not guaranteed to throw, then there would be a non-negligible chance that an incorrect password would not be detected. If I then give this user access to unencrypted functionality, that would be a serious security flaw. In other words, authentication != decryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question straight away: Decrypting a ciphertext with an wrong key, i.e. a key that was not used in the encryption, does *not* necessarily result in an exception.

The following C# code shows the decryption of a ciphertext with three keys (the ciphertext was generated with AES/CBC and PKCS#7 padding):

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
...
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    byte[] iv = Convert.FromHexString("4B4D907F815EAB0EA3E8A2140968C395");
    byte[] ciphertext = Convert.FromHexString("4A9BE2E236868EC0D04F0D280A2876920F79C10969F32D751FF1976E6446F7BBF2469957130E4EE1CC56C386426E1C5C");

    // 1. 
    testCase(1, Convert.FromHexString("5DBF2259D534802EA0C8B24FD6CA876C345AE4C4AE2E000BCB05B33E7465FAEF"), iv, ciphertext);

    // 2. 
    testCase(2, Convert.FromHexString("DFAC3EDECC5F53EF1ACFEE07085A2A5C4327D1057BED2405D5E18EF12DE05C63"), iv, ciphertext);

    // 3. 
    testCase(3, Convert.FromHexString("000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F"), iv, ciphertext);
}

private static void testCase(int num, byte[] key, byte[] iv, byte[] ciphertext)
{
    Console.WriteLine("" + num + ".");
    try
    {
        byte[] decryptedNone = Decrypt(ciphertext, key, iv, PaddingMode.None);
        byte[] decryptedPkcs7 = Decrypt(ciphertext, key, iv, PaddingMode.PKCS7);
        Console.WriteLine("before depadding: " + Convert.ToHexString(decryptedNone));
        Console.WriteLine("after depadding:  " + Convert.ToHexString(decryptedPkcs7));
        Console.WriteLine("UTF-8 decoded:    " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedPkcs7));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

private static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV, PaddingMode pm)
{
    byte[] plaintext = null;
    using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        aesAlg.Key = Key;
        aesAlg.IV = IV;
        aesAlg.Padding = pm;
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
        {
            using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (MemoryStream plainTextStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    csDecrypt.CopyTo(plainTextStream);
                    plaintext = plainTextStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
            msDecrypt.Close();
        }
    }
    return plaintext;
}
```

- The 1st decryption uses the correct key. The last 5 bytes of the decrypted plaintext are 0x05050505. This is compliant with PKCS#7, i.e. the padding is valid and will be removed automatically. The decryption is successful, the plaintext is the same as the original plaintext.
- The 2nd decryption uses a wrong key. By chance the last 2 bytes of the decrypted plaintext are 0x0202, which is also compliant with PKCS#7. Therefore this data is interpreted as valid padding and removed automatically. No exception is thrown. Of course, the decryption is not successful because the plaintext does not match the original plaintext.
- The 3rd decryption also uses a wrong key. Here the last bytes are not compliant with PKCS#7. Therefore this is interpreted as invalid padding and a corresponding exception is thrown (*CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed*).

Accordingly, the output is:

```
1.
before depadding: 54686520717569636B2062726F776E20666F78206A756D7073206F76657220746865206C617A7920646F670505050505
after depadding:  54686520717569636B2062726F776E20666F78206A756D7073206F76657220746865206C617A7920646F67
UTF-8 decoded:    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

2.
before depadding: 4D5B5017ADF3B5EFB5716AB2CCFF8BA6129E35A123287CD564F12C2401AB985EEBC7E274B685595251059C56E2BC0202
after depadding:  4D5B5017ADF3B5EFB5716AB2CCFF8BA6129E35A123287CD564F12C2401AB985EEBC7E274B685595251059C56E2BC
UTF-8 decoded:    M[P↨???qj?????↕?5?#(|?d?,$☺??^???t??YRQ♣?V?

3.
Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.
```

---

What are the probabilities for 2., i.e. for the case that a wrong key does *not* cause an exception? For PKCS#7 the value of the padding bytes corresponds to the number of padding bytes, i.e. the following paddings are possible for AES with a block size of 16 bytes, see [PKCS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7) for details:

```
0x01, 0x0202, 0x030303, ..., 0x10101010101010101010101010101010 (full block)
```

The probability, for a 0x01 at the end is 265<sup>-1</sup>, for 0x0202 265<sup>-2</sup>, etc. up to 265<sup>-16</sup> for the full block. I.e. especially the contribution of the small padding bytes to the probability is not negligible.

The above probabilities apply under the assumption that all padding bytes are checked (which may not be true for all implementations). If fewer padding bytes are checked, the probability increases, see the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71641514/9014097).

---

So far, block cipher modes (such as CBC) have been considered, which generally require mandatory padding. There are also stream cipher modes (such as CTR) that do not require padding. For these, no exception is generally thrown because of the missing padding.

---

As noted in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71639063/is-cryptostream-flushfinalblock-guaranteed-to-throw-an-exception-when-the-key-is#comment126613401_71639063) and elaborated in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71641514/9014097), authenticated encryption/decryption (e.g. GCM) provides a reliable way to detect whether the ciphertext has been tampered with and also whether the correct key is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Usually (and for .NET by default, for ECB and CBC, with CBC being the default) PKCS#7 compatible padding is used. In that case the result of a wrong key is a fully randomized final plaintext block. The chance of correct padding is about one in 2^256 for a single padding byte (the next ones are less and less likely, 1 in 65536 etc, so they are relatively inconsequential). Some unpadding routines will (incorrectly) only check the last byte, in which case the chance is 16 out of 256, or 1 out of 16.

For PKCS#7, the padding is **always** added. This makes sense because the decryption routine doesn't know the length, and the (binary) message may end with padding bytes by chance - as already established. So you'd have 16 bytes values 0x10. As unpadding is still used, the chance of creating a valid padding is of course still 1 in 256, as the unpadding routine doesn't know the padding used.

To get around issues with the padding you need an authentication tag. That tag can be generated by using a HMAC over the ciphertext *while including the IV if that can be altered by an attacker*. You could also use GCM mode, which has been added to .NET not too long ago (i.e. very, very late), which is both more efficient as less error prone (you don't have to explicitly include the IV and verification is more or less a given).

Note that the result of unpadding can also be used for padding oracle attacks, which are a type of plaintext oracle attack created by just having availability of a decrypt routine. These attacks can fully retrieve the plaintext by performing average 128 decryption ops per byte.

Comment: Thanks. Ok just so I'm clear, the short answer to my question is - no, FlushFinalBlock is NOT guaranteed to throw if the key is wrong - correct?